# Knockout.js template-wide semi-global variables

Tags: knockout.js

Is there any way to define (in lack of a better term)"semi-global" variables for KO?

I'd like to make a variable available to a single KO template regardless of context while keeping it from the actual global scope and other templates.

The objective is to have a set of helper functions that are only available to that one template in any binding context(e.g. inside KO's foreach) without using *$parent*, just like globals are always accessible without any special syntax. Example below:

```
// Template 1 - helpers.foo has been set for this Template or ViewModel
<div data-bind="text:helpers.foo('Works')"></div>
<div data-bind="foreach: someList">
    <div data-bind="text:helpers.foo('Context is inside someList. helpers.foo is not available :( ')"></div>
</div>

// Template 2 - helpers.foo is not set for this Template or ViewModel
<div data-bind="text:helpers.foo('Should not work')"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure yet but I think I found the solution. After browsing through KO documentation for the n'th time I found this: [Supplying additional values to descendant bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html#example_supplying_additional_values_to_descendant_bindings).

For those of you who tl;dr:
I can use that custom binding handler to expose any variable to the template in every subcontext, which is exactly what I was looking for. In other words this becomes possible:

**ViewModel**

```
<script>
ViewModel = {
    Helpers: {
        foo: function(message) {return message;}
    },
    someList: [
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'baz'
    ]
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="text:helpers.foo('Helpers.foo can be used because we are in the root context')"></div>

<div data-bind="foreach: someList">
    <div data-bind="text:helpers.foo('We are in the context of someList. This will fail.')"></div>
</div>

<div data-bind="withProperties:{Helpers:Helpers}">
    <div data-bind="foreach: someList">
        <div data-bind="text:helpers.foo('Helpers.foo can now be used inside every subcontext, thanks to the withProperties custom binding')"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my case the custom binding wrapper can be applied automatically upon load for every template, so this seems like a great solution for me!

I'll try this method and post a follow-up if it happens that I've overlooked something. This question will be left open for a short while because I can't accept my own answer so quickly. Meanwhile feel free to post your solutions, I'm sure there are more approaches to solving this.

Answer (score 2):

You should define new custom binding that fetches values from your "helper". Just for simple example:

```
// your "semi-globally" accessible helpers
var helpers = {
    foo: function(text){ return "<b>" + text + "</b>"; },
    boo: function(text){ return "<u>" + text + "</u>"; }
};

// custom binding
ko.bindingHandlers.helpers = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var opts = valueAccessor();
        element.innerHTML = helpers[opts.name].apply(element, opts.args);
    }
};

// two different primitive ViewModels without any ref to helpers
function VM_1 () { this.name = "vm-1"; }
function VM_2 () { this.name = "vm-2"; }

// binding models
ko.applyBindings(new VM_1, document.getElementById("vm-1"));
ko.applyBindings(new VM_2, document.getElementById("vm-2"));
```

HTML:

```
<div id="vm-1">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <span data-bind="helpers: { name: 'foo', args: ['Works!'] }"></span>
</div>

<div id="vm-2">
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <span data-bind="helpers: { name: 'foo', args: ['Works perfectly!'] }"></span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ostgals/GfBJ9/1/

Comment: That's my current fallback solution. Not ideal, since the helpers would be shared between templates but kind of works. I'll wait a while for other answers and if nothing else works, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Sorry, seems I haven't understood your question. I thought you want to share some variables between different models rather than between contexts of one model. :)

Comment: No problem. I could've expressed myself better in the question too :)